# Php string to multilevel lists HTML

Tags: php, string, html-lists

I have file

animals.txt

```
fishes   shark,tuna,salmon
birds    parrot,pigeon
mammals  cow,dog,cat
```

In every line, for example between fishes and shark is tabulation.

I wanna get this output:

```
<ul type="disc">
            <li>fishes<br>
                <ul type="disc">
                    <li>shark</li>
                    <li>tuna</li>
                    <li>salmon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>birds<br>
                <ul type="disc">
                    <li>parrot</li>
                    <li>pigeon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>mammals<br>
                <ul type="disc">
                    <li>cow</li>
                    <li>dog</li>
                    <li>cat</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I wrote simple code, but I don't know what can I do next, can someone help me solve it?

index.php

```
$file = fopen('animals.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $a = explode(" ", $line);
    $b = str_replace(",", " ", $a);
    $c = explode(" ", $b);
    print_r($b);


}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you made a start and then just.... stopped. My only point at this stage is that you should be exploding on comma in your second explode, not replacing commas with spaces and splitting on spaces.

Comment: I know, but im looking for clue or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply going to read that file and not write in it, maybe using `file` will be simpler than `fopen` as it creates an array of lines.

You'll want to *double explode* every line, once on the tabulation to separate **family** and **animals** and a second time to split **animals** individually.

To create a nicely structure array of families and animals, try the following and add some `var_dump`  at different steps to see the logic:

```
$file = file('animals.txt');

$groupedAnimals = array();
foreach ($file as $line) {
    // First explode on tabulations
    $line = explode("\t", $line);

    $family = $line[0];
    // Then explode on commas
    $animals = explode(',', $line[1]);

    foreach ($animals as $animal) {
        $groupedAnimals[$family][] = $animal;
    }
}
```

The `groupedAnimals` array should be populated like that:

```
Array
(
    [fishes] => Array
        (
            [0] => shark
            [1] => tuna
            [2] => salmon

        )

    [birds] => Array
        (
            [0] => parrot
            [1] => pigeon

        )

    [mammals] => Array
        (
            [0] => cow
            [1] => dog
            [2] => cat
        )

)
```

Once the `groupedAnimals` array is populated, you can simply print them the way you want, following your template:

```
<ul type="disc">
    <?php foreach ($groupedAnimals as $family => $animals): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $family ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($animals as $animal): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $animal ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function xxAxx(){

    $output='';

    $file = fopen('animals.txt', 'r');
    while (!feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        //replace white spaces with a different delimiter
        $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $line);
        $line = trim($line);
        // explode with your delemeter
        $a = explode("-", $line);
        $category = $a[0];
        $categoryItems = explode(",", $a[1]);

        $output .= "<li>".$category ."<br>";
        $output .= "<ul type='disc'>";
        foreach ($categoryItems as $item) {
            $output .= '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
        }
        $output .= "</ul>";
        $output .= "</li>";

    }
    fclose($file);

    return $output;
}

?>

<ul type="disc">
    <?php echo xxAxx(); ?>
</ul>
```